# Custom auto-complete with UltiSnips in vim

Tags: python, vim, ultisnips

I would like to create snippets that do a custom completion at each tab stop using Vim's `complete()` function. Here's a simple example of what i want to achieve.

```
snippet date "Date snippet"
   day of month: ${1:`!v complete(col('.'), [1, 2, 3, 4])`}
   month: ${2:`!v complete(col('.'), ['Jan', 'Feb', 'March'])`}
   year: ${3:`!v complete(col('.'), ['2012', '2013', '2014', '2015'])`}
endsnippet
```

At the first tab stop i want to see Vim's auto-complete menu with `[1, 2, 3, 4]` items. Similarly for other tab stops. But, when i actually run this snippet I get the following output

```
day of month: Jan0an0
month: 201200120
year:100
```

There might be other ways to achieve auto-complete as shown in screen cast [Episode 4: Python Interpolation](http://www.sirver.net/blog/2012/03/31/fourth-episode-of-ultisnips-screencast/). But, I would love to see Vim's auto-complete inside UltiSnips.

Please anyone suggest on how to achieve this.

Comment: I'm using VIM 7.4 on Win 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, due to Vim's design, this is not achievable in vanilla Vim+UltiSnips today. It might be doable once neovim fixes interaction issues.

See https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/issues/428